# pointcloud_to_laserscan with camera pointed downward

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so, I have d435 intel realsense camera and it is mounted at 1.3 meters above the floor:
[image: image description]

I've tried to use pointcloud_to_laserscan package and I've got laserscan data angled:
[image: image description]

How can I get laserscan data parallel to the floor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332870/pointcloud_to_laserscan-with-camera-pointed-downward/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-09-12**:
similar question and not answered yet: https://answers.ros.org/question/268861/how-to-use-pointcloud_to_laserscan-with-an-angled-sensor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your getting this problem because [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) is using your RGB-D cameras frame of reference instead of a leveled one which compensates for it's angle.

You can use the `~target_frame` parameter to reference a different TF frame which can fix this.

You'll need to use a [static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) to add a new frame to your robot with the z axis facing horizontally away from the base and y axis pointing down. Then set the `~target_frame` parameter to this new frame.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-09-12**:
thanks, it helped

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-09-12**:
why new frame? can i just set it to base_footprint frame?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-09-12**:
It depends if `pointcloud_to_laserscan` uses the optical frame convention instead of the standard ROS frame convention. So the `base_footprint` frame may be oriented the wrong way for this. But give it a try and let us know.